# How can I drag a subview out of the parent view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview

So in my app I have a `UIImageView[1]` that takes up about the top half of the screen. I also have a TapGesture recognizer that adds a `UIImageView[2]` as a subview of `UIImageView[1]`.

In the bottom half of my application I have another `UIImageView[3]` I need the `UIImageView[2]`'s to be able to interact with.
However, when I drag the `UIImageView[2]` outside the frame of `UIImageView[1]` it obviously disappears.
I was wondering if anyone knew a way I could drag `UIImageView[2]` to `UIImageView[3]` without `UIImageView[2]` disappearing while still maintaining the frame of `UIImageView[1]`.

I've tried resizing `UIImageView[1]` to just encompass the whole screen but since I'm using Aspect Fit it centers the image and if I use the top left align thing it doesn't aspect fit it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this to disable subview clipping:

```
[parentView clipsToBounds:NO];
```

Comment: This works but then if I go to drag the image again I can't touch it again even though UserInteraction is enabled. Any ideas? Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following for dragging `UIImageView[2]` any where else in view

```
[self.view addsubview: UIImageView[2]];
```

Comment: This works and lets me me touch it outside the view but it makes some CGRectIntersectsRect statements I have act really strangely (it makes the statements get called even if the two are not touching). Any Ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: This one sorry I forgot to add it.                                                                         if (CGRectIntersectsRect(UIImageView[2], UIImageView[3].frame) || (CGRectEqualToRect(UIImageView[2], UIImageView[3].frame))  {
                UIImageView *selectedimage = [_myArray objectAtIndex:0];
                [selectedimage removeFromSuperview];
            }

Comment: @Pecans it will be better if you edit your question and add above lines, it will also help other to understand your problem better.